# How do you control the "SET" statements emitted by Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there any way to control the "SET" statements that Linq to SQL emits?  I see these SET options coming from Linq to SQL in the SQL profiler and it turns out that "set arithabort off" is causing one of our procs to take 45 seconds as opposed to < 1 second.

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the default constructor or passing a connection string, create your own `IDbConnection`, set whatever options you need, then pass that to your `DataContext`'s constructor.

Comment: I don't see an option to set arithabort to ON in the SqlConnection object.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should just be able to execute any of those options as a SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: No problem! If this has answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as the answer! :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this for EF4, I've been looking for a way, but not having much luck yet.

Comment: @Grubsnik: Since this question is about L2S and yours is about EF4, please post that as a new question; you'll also get a lot more attention that way!